# Intel(R) HD Graphics does not work on DELL Inspiron 15 7560

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1, graphics-card

I have a DELL Inspiron 15 series 7000 (i15-7560-A30S) from a customer, where the default operating system was **Windows 10 Home Single Language**, after performing a series of repairs like DC Jack connector replacement, power supply shorted and problems on the SSD M2, I made the necessary repairs and installed **Windows 8.1** on the SSD

After installing all the necessary drivers, even the one for the dedicated *NVIDIA GeForce 940MX* graphics card, I had a little problem installing the driver for the integrated graphics card, which in this case is Intel(R) HD Graphics.

On the DELL Driver Support website https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/inspiron-15-7560-laptop/drivers it returns the video drivers to me integrated and dedicated, when I try to install it on the system it gives me the following error

> There is no support for this installation package in this type of processor

The processor of this notebook is an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz`

#### Trying in every way...

I pressed the keys <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and clicked on **System** and then I went to **Device Manager**

and there it presents me only the primary **Driver Basic Video Adapter from Microsoft**. I tried to upgrade, but the system informs you that this is the best driver available.

I also made attempts in some driver installation programs, but did not succeed, as:

- Driver Booster
- DriverPack Solution
- Slim Drivers
- DriversCloud
- DriverHub
- Device Doctor

but they reported that they had no available driver or even had but it was incompatible with the system and between others.

<sup>Note: I didn't find anything that can fix my problem on the Intel website, they are only supporting recent versions of Windows 10 64bit. The way will be to migrate system?</sup>

Comment: _"[Intel] are only supporting recent versions of Windows 10 64bit"_ - that's your answer, isn't it?

Comment: @gronostaj Not necessarily, I would like to find a solution to continue using Windows 8.1, but fix this problem because DELL notebooks have already passed me where the integrated boards were also from the Intel(R) line and worked perfectly!

Comment: I understand that it's your wish to stick to Win8.1. Nevertheless, you weren't able to find a driver that would work on Windows 8.1 and Intel says they don't support Windows 8.1. I don't think that's a coincidence.

Comment: Well, friend, it will be the way to migrate the system same. After I installed some security updates through Windows Update, after restarting it gave me the following message:

Comment: *"Incompatible Hardware: Your computer uses a processor that is designed for the latest version of Windows. Since the processor is not compatible with the version of Windows you are using, your system will miss important security updates. Select the "Learn more" link to resolve this situation."*